# How to add icons to items in listview in android navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

Iam beginner in Android Development , so i followed tutorial from http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/  , i would like to add icons to listview in android navigation drawerm, plz help me in fixing this

here is my nav_drawer_row.xml source :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my NavigationDrawerAdapter.java source :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Ravi Tamada on 12-03-2015.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<NavDrawerItem> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(Context context, List<NavDrawerItem> data) {
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void delete(int position) {
        data.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_drawer_row, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is FragmentDrawer.java source:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialdesign.R;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.adapter.NavigationDrawerAdapter;
import info.androidhive.materialdesign.model.NavDrawerItem;

public class FragmentDrawer extends Fragment {

    private static String TAG = FragmentDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private static String[] titles = null;
    private FragmentDrawerListener drawerListener;

    public FragmentDrawer() {

    }

    public void setDrawerListener(FragmentDrawerListener listener) {
        this.drawerListener = listener;
    }

    public static List<NavDrawerItem> getData() {
        List<NavDrawerItem> data = new ArrayList<>();


        // preparing navigation drawer items
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
            NavDrawerItem navItem = new NavDrawerItem();
            navItem.setTitle(titles[i]);
            data.add(navItem);
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // drawer labels
        titles = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_labels);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflating view layout
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);

        adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                drawerListener.onDrawerItemSelected(view, position);
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        return layout;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, final Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset / 2);
            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }


    }

    public interface FragmentDrawerListener {
        public void onDrawerItemSelected(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: This tutorial is relatively old. search for NavigationView you'll find better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a custom layout for your Navigation Drawer. Then you will be able to add images and  even expandable lists. Here is a tutorial for you.

http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

You can set drawableLeft property in xml.

Or you can set programatically.

You can use any of the following methods for setting the Drawable on TextView:

1- setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

2- setCompoundDrawables(Left_Drawable, Top_Drawable, Right_Drawable, Bottom_Drawable)

And to get drawable from resources you can use:

getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable_id);

Comment: as i mentioned  i am begineer , plz help me with code if possible